# Retrieving Image From Database w/sql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, pdo

So i think this question has been addressed before but none of the answers seem to help me.
I have uploaded a .jpeg file to my database by extracting the content from the file and uploaded that to a BLOB field in my database. When it comes to retrieving the data I search the database using an id set by the query string ?id=146 (I've inserted a value that relates to a specific entry in my database just to check the functionality). When I then echo the image['image'] the binary data displays fine (well the browser renders the data how it interprets it) so its finding the entry I want, and it displays the data fine. When I add header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); and reload the page the browser tells me the image is missing. ![screen shot of missing image display][1]

The entire functionality will work as i will reference the php file in the src of an  tag on the page I want the image to display. But I can't even get the image to load onto the php page when I type in its URL(inc the correct query string).

Here is a my code for the php page to find the image:

```
$id = intval(addslashes($_REQUEST['id']));
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cefk_profile` WHERE `id`=$id");
$result->execute();
$image = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $image['img'];
```

And here is a shot of the page that will display the picture:

```
echo '<img src="php/get_img.php?id=146">';
```

Comment: Better question: WHY are you saving an image in a database. Other than really really fringe use cases you should never do that. Access control can be done by piping an image from file system via php script to user.

Comment: which browser did you use to test?